# writing a java array and getting too many outputs

Tags: java, arrays

```
// declare an array (named numbs) that holds 10 ints
int[] numbs = new int[10];
// write a for loop that loops 10 times and generates a random number between 0 and 100
for (int i = 0; i < numbs.length; i++) {
    numbs[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
}
// print the values
for (int number : numbs) {
    System.out.println(number);

    // write a for loop that displays to the screen each random number in the array named numbs
    for (int i = 0; i < numbs.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("the random number for element " + i + " is " + numbs[i]);
    }
}
```

I want my final output to only show ten numbers but what i get is 10 numbers repeated 10 times so instead of
the random number for element 1 is 1
the random number for element 2 is 2
the random number... etc to ten

I get
the random number for element 1 is 1
the random number for element 2 is 2
the random number... etc to ten
then it goes back to the top number and prints 
"the random number for element 1 is 1" again
and then "the random number for element 2 is 2" again

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You get exactly what you instruct Java to give you.  Observe the nested `for` loops.

Comment: Indeed - if you get your IDE to format your code for you, it'll be a lot clearer.

Comment: Why are you using multiple (nested) `for` loops? It appears that you only wanted the second, but I can't tell whether you want to print the array twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using nested for-loops. You only need your third for loop.

> ```
> public class FArray {
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>   int[] numbs = new int[10];
>   for (int i = 0; i < numbs.length; i++) {
>     numbs[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
>   }
>   // print the values
>   for (int i=0; i<numbs.length; i++) {
>     System.out.println("the random number for element "+ i +" is "+numbs[i]);
>   }
>  }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You getting data printed 10 times X 10 times because you have a nested loop notice may be you wanted somthing like this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declare an array (named numbs) that holds 10 ints
    int[] numbs = new int[10];
    // write a for loop that loops 10 times and generates a random number
    // between 0 and 100
    for (int i = 0; i < numbs.length; i++) {
        numbs[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    }

    // write a for loop that displays to the screen each random number in
    // the array named numbs
    for (int i = 0; i < numbs.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("the random number for element " + i + " is " + numbs[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> *I want my final output to only show ten numbers but what i get is 10 numbers repeated 10 times so instead of the random number for element
> 1 is 1 the random number for element 2 is 2 the random number... etc
> to ten*

you are looping **2** times, one for loop is more than ok to see all the random elements in the array...  remove one of the both loops (e.g. remove the enhanced for loop) to see only the 10 numbers you generated..

## Example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // declare an array (named numbs) that holds 10 ints
        int[] numbs = new int[10];
        // write a for loop that loops 10 times and generates a random number between 0 and 100
        for (int i = 0; i < numbs.length; i++) {
            numbs[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        }
        // print the values

        // write a for loop that displays to the screen each random number in the array named numbs
        for (int i = 0; i < numbs.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("the random number for element " + i + " is " + numbs[i]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The final part of your code:

```
for (int number : numbs) {
    System.out.println(number);
// write a for loop that displays to the screen each random number in the array named numbs
for (int i = 0; i < numbs.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("the random number for element " + i + " is " + numbs[i]);
}
```

You are telling it to do the following:
foreach int stored in the array numbs, print that int, and then, foreach element numbs[i] with i=0..numbs.length-1 print that sentence.

So, you have 10 elements in your array. For each element, you are checking all the positions of the array, again. That is the reason why you are getting 10*10 results.

It would be enough to write the following:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numbs.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("the random number for element " + i + " is " + numbs[i]);
  }
```